# Dissect a square-and-a-half into 4 equal pieces

Tags: geometry, dissection

The following shape is has the proportions of a square attached to a similar square divided diagonally - A *square and a half*, if you may.

[image]

The puzzle is to **dissect the shape into 4 [congruent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_%28geometry%29) pieces.**

> Two figures or objects are **congruent** if they have the same shape and size, or if one has the same shape and size as the mirror image of the other.

Comment: Can the pieces be mirror images of each other?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. But extra points if they aren't ;).

Comment: they must be [congruent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_%28geometry%29) then

Comment: Yes. I think it's more clear now. I was looking to avoid a mathematical term, though.

Comment: I know how to do this, but I need to use graphics software.

Comment: @JoeZ. go MS paint? there is also the paper pencil camera and wooden table option

Comment: @JoeZ. Well, you could give a rough idea (using MS Paint, if you're using Windows). I initally thought of adding some critical points so you could just tell me the congruent polygons, but that would have just ruined the fun.

Comment: For future reference, [LiveGeometry](http://livegeometry.com/) is a wonderful tool.

Comment: It requires Silverlight, though, which I don't have on this Linux box.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The first thing to do is divide the figure into a number of sections which is a multiple of four. The easiest way to do this is to split it up into smaller triangles:

[image: triangle division]

Note that there are now 12 sections, which divides into sections of 3. Three triangles forms a  square and a smaller triangle. We know, as a result, that a square must go here (another way to do this is that the triangle in the corner must be part of a shape of three parts):

[image]

From this, it becomes clear where the rest of the divisions lie. The remaining triangle, as part of the triangular section, must be part of a set of three, so as a result, we know that it is as follows:

[image]

The rest of the divisions are simple:

[image]

And, as a side note, for future reference, [LiveGeometry](http://livegeometry.com/) is a wonderful little tool.

Comment: This one's way better than mine.

Comment: @JoeZ. We have the same solution, though, to be fair!

Comment: @John I won't choose for you, since that would be incredibly biased, but the canonical advice from Meta Stack Exchange on this topic is available [in this FAQ answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/206222) under "Which answer should I choose?"

Comment: @JohnBupit An answer with an explanation is always more useful than one with just the answer. (Not to say anything bad about Joe's answer; just in general.) That said, anyone can upvote either and your checkmark is yours to place :)

Comment: I would personally recommend you accept this answer (which you seem to have done, congrats).

Answer (score 8):

The solution appears as follows:

[image: solution to the puzzle]

It's a bit rough, but it shows the right places to cut the shape.